# Django model ManytoMany getters

Tags: django, methods, admin, models, getter

I wanted to get a list of objects associated to model A by ManyToMany with model B, e.g. diners (A) confirmed to attend a meal(B). But I'm not sure what getter I should use. I actually wanted to do this to show the associated objects in the admin panel. The method included beneath was one failed attempt I made.

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    diners = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Attendance', related_name="eating", blank=True)

    def diners(self):
        return self.eating
```

Can you help?
Thanks

Comment: self.diners.all() is'n what you need?

Answer (score 1):

As ilvar suggested, remove diners method and use self.diners.all() to get objects inside Meal methods. related_name='eating' is for fetching attended meals of a user, reversely.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. So in the Meal models, I put:

     `def eating(self):
         return self.diners.all()`

and in the MealAdmin file I put:

    `class MealAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('summary', 'when', 'host', 'url', 'diners')
    pass

admin.site.register(Meal, MealAdmin)`

This gives me the error:

**Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value: 
'MealAdmin.list_display[4]', 'diners' is a ManyToManyField which is not supported.**

Comment: @user77510 list_display does not support ManyToManyField. If you want to show items of the dinner field in admin change_list, you need to write some method to render the content of the column directly, refs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: Yes I have seen that, which is how this thread started. I tried to make that method as above, and according to your method above, but I then I encounter the above. That method doesn't seem to work. What do you reckon? Thanks

Comment: @user77510 just output the html snippet you want. For example, showing all dinner by their \_\_unicode__ would be "return ','.join(map(unicode, self.diners.all()))". You could start a new question about the way of implementing the method if you are still confused.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this page with the same problem as OP. I ended up simply removing the reference to the ManyToMany field in `list_display` in my admin model. The result: on the admin page for that app, under the ManyToMany field name, appeared a nicely formatted multi-selection list widget with the possible values for my ManyToMany relationship shown.

So the solution was to remove the reference in `list_display` and let Django handle it. This is with Django 1.4.3.